# share folders over network across OSs

Tags: windows, linux, wireless-networking

I have a desktop with ubuntu 10.04 with my whole music collection in it. I want to access it using my laptop and my brother's laptop, both running windows (vista and 7 respectively).

How do I do that?

All are connected to the same network.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

install samba

example of /etc/samba/smb.conf

```
[global]
netbios name = musicserver
workgroup = WORKGROUP
server string = Music server
security = share

[public]
path = /path/to/music
guest ok = yes
read only = no
```